# Applescript Click in Safari and Chrome

Tags: applescript, safari, google-chrome

I am trying to click a button on a webpage using Applescript, other than using the class name, which I have achieved. The buttons have other identifiers that are more precise without the need to identify the button number needed in a series. I was wondering if there is a script that I can use in Chrome and one for Safari that would allow me to click by button data-nodeid= "using a name or number of data-nodeid" in this case "5", as seen in the attached picture. Also by aria-controls= "name or number of aria-controls" in this case "HoverCard-212291165076", as seen in the attached picture.

Please advise!

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your question is unclear. Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/459201/edit) to add additional details that will help others understand and eventually answer the question. You can find more information on how to write good questions in the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).